# Not Able to Access Virtual Folder JBOSS 5.1.0

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x, java-6

I am newbie to jboss.  We have configured jboss in Oracle linux, we are using three servers for example www.mysite.com/CIMM2EVENT,www.mysite.com/CIMM2Engman,www.mysite.com/CIMM2Taylor.  We are using private IP address for backend server as JBOSS and public IP for HAProxy for eg:162.214.122.89  and virtual folder is located in /usr/image_folder.  We can access the site without any error but when accessing virtualfolder for eg:www.mysite.com/Document/data.pdf it is going for 404 not found error.
     I have tried changing the name of the virtual folder for all diffrent servers it also not solved my issue.  Kindly suggest to get me out of the issue i am trying from past two days.  Any suggestions would be appreciable.

Comment: hey. you cannot access folders just like that . you should have a servlet and that servlet should return you the PDF files or watever files it is ..

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer the problem was we are using same domain name for three jboss instances which had configured in three different Server. When we hit the site it was working fine but when we access the document or image which had configured in virtual path it was confused because all the servers virtual folder are in the same name for ex:www.mysite.com/Documents/mydata.pdf so it was hitting not the intended server. We have changed all the three domain name's now it is working fine......Thanks.

Comment: give upvote to my comment. if u find it right